# Removing lines from a file containing few keywords

Tags: c

I have a file with 2 million lines(filepaths) in it. Now I wanted to remove the lines having these strings in them (.jpg,.bmp, .css, .html, etc). I think the program looks correct but it is also removing the  other lines having extensions like .bak, log files. please help with the correct code. I just wanted to remove some file extensions like (.html,.css) in the total filepath list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main ( void )
{
   static const char filename[] = "file.txt";
   FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
   char *s,*t,*u,*v,*w,*x,*y,*z;
   int c=0;
   FILE *f;
   f=fopen("out.txt","w");
  
   char line [ 999999 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
   while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
   {
         //fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
         s=strstr(line,".png");
         t=strstr(line,".jpg");
         u=strstr(line,".bmp");
         v=strstr(line,".gif");
         w=strstr(line,".js");
         x=strstr(line,".htm");
         y=strstr(line,".css");
         z=strstr(line,".swf");
               
         if((s==NULL)&&(t==NULL)&&(u==NULL)&&(v==NULL)&&(w==NULL)&&(x==NULL)&&(y==NULL)&&(z==NULL))
         {
                c=c+1;
                fprintf(f,"%s",line);
         }
   }
   fclose ( file );
   fclose ( f );
   printf("%d",c);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using already existing tools for regular expressions, instead of writing a dedicated application? On Linux for example, the desired result could easily be achieved by e.g. piping your file through `sed` or `grep`

Comment: Please provide sample input showing the error.

Comment: I am on windows and There is no error, it is also removing the other lines

Comment: @udaydatrak what do the file contents look like exactly?

Comment: Your code also works perfectly fine for me, it removes the correct lines and keeps the others - your file formatting is probably not what you expect it to be

Comment: At a preliminary analysis your code looks fine to me, except for the fact that it will remove also files such as `foo.bmp.bak`.

Comment: As a side note, i'd recommend to put all the extensions in a `char*` array and then check them using another loop. By doing this you can get rid of the multiple `strstr` calls, as well as the huge if condition, making it easier to add or remove file extensions later.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have identifed that once the code reached the line number 235,548. its getting terminatted from the loop. can you guys tell me how can I fix this issue and make sure read all the lines in the file?

Comment: Fixed by justed making a small change while reading file "r" to "rb"

Comment: I would never use C for something like this. I'd use Bash (linux) or Python. I'm sure Powershell would be able to handle this well.

Comment: Well, even `FINDSTR` of a recent Windows `cmd` can do this.

Comment: IMHO judging if C is the best fit or not for this task is out of the scope of the _answerers_. The question is clearly about performing a specific task in C.